# SQL Server different design query performance

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have been trying to check the performance of different types of database designs, but I am not sure if the results I get are correct.

I have two databases, with the different tables, but meant to store the same information.

1. In my first design I put all my fields in one table.
2. In second design I have multiple tables and want to use joins to find my records.

See the image for more detailed information:

[image]

When I run the query below against first database it executes in 0.03 sec.

```
SELECT 
    a.[idPerson], a.[Id], a.[Description], a.[LastName], a.[nme], 
    a.[Email], a.[Phone], a.[grp] 
FROM 
    [Student] a 
WHERE 
    a.[grp] = 'R3PU56' 
    AND a.[nme] = 'tZv5oxqSDEoXPnU' 
    AND a.[Email] = 'gyRpWWCopv'
```

When I run the query below against second database it executes in 0.03 sec too.

```
SELECT 
    a.[Id], a.[grp], b.[Email], b.[Phone], 
    c.[Description], c.[LastName], c.[nme] 
FROM 
    [Student2] a 
JOIN 
    [AdvancedPerson2] AS b ON (a.[Id] = b.[Id]) 
JOIN 
    [Person2] AS c ON (a.[Id] = c.[Id]) 
WHERE 
    a.[grp] = 'R3PU56' 
    AND b.[Email] = 'gyRpWWCopv'
    AND c.[nme] = 'tZv5oxqSDEoXPnU'
```

I was expecting the second query will take much more than first query because of joins. My question is, why both quesries are takingsame amount of time? If they are the same which database strucure should I use? Some people might say that second structure is complicated because of multiple tables, but I don't care. I am using **Telerik ORM** and both seems the same in C# code.

Comment: if the number of rows is shorter that 4 figures (don't take '4 figures' as a rule! it is just a rough indication) and the server is not under load it is almost impossible to have differences using such simple queries and structures. the issue is your expectation: you can't 'guess' the performances just looking at the tables and you are not taking in consideration the optimization made by various rdbms components behind the scenes.

Comment: You may find useful [the classical description and comparison of different inheritance mapping strategies](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqr/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your first case, denormalize table, should be quicker in theory, but DB do a good job making the normalized version be pretty quick as well despise the extra work with joins. You will probably only notice the benefits of the denormalized schema if you have huge amounts of data.

Regarding which schema to use, I think I would go for the second one, but without the Advanced Person 2 table, why do you need it?

Comment: Just for testing purposes I have the Person2 table
 this is not my real database design.

Answer (score 1):

Flattened data structures almost always can perform better, but the difference in properly indexed databases can be quite small. In your case, it also looks like a flattened data structure would use less space as well.

That said, database design should be more about logical grouping. Sometimes flattened is better; most of the time, normalized is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the performance part of the question, but I wouldn't agree with either of your designs if I'm honest.

I'd probably go for something like this instead:

**Teacher**

```
Id (PK) 
PersonId (FK)
```

**Student**

```
Id (PK) 
PersonId (FK)
```

**Person**

Both teachers and students are classified as People with personal contact type information. Not sure why you need the `AdvancedPerson` table when it's a 1 to 1 mapping.

```
Id (PK)
FirstName
LastName
Tel
Email
-- other contact type info
```

**Subject**

Table just for subjects with the Id of the teacher. This assumes the subject only has a single teacher.

```
Id (PK)
TeacherId (FK)
SubjectName
```

**StudentSubject**

Link table to group students and the subjects they take.

```
StudentId (FK)
SubjectId (FK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which query has a better performance, you have to compare a bit more than just runing time. You simple query can just trigger the statistic update and this is not what you want to measure. 
run following code:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON
```

and run you queries again. It gives you more information about the query.